# Cannot figure how to get header data out of GroupBy loop in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm lost on correct syntax for getting a specific Model item to display just inside a `Foreach` grouping loop.  Feeding with a `IEnumerable Model` from the controller.. Sub loop and outer loop work perfectly, just cannot get the value for the inner to header and define the Top of each inside loops values

View Code:

```
@model IEnumerable<eManager.Web2.Models.EventClassCompListVM>

<table class="table">



    <h2>
        @(Model.Any() ? Model.First().EventName : "")
        @(Model.Any() ? Model.First().EventDate.ToShortDateString() : "")

    </h2>

    @foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(item => item.ClassName))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClassName)
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ClassName) //Generates an unknown exception
            </td>
        </tr>
        foreach (var item in group)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comp_EventID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompName)
```

ViewModel  //Made up of 4 Models of specific elements

```
namespace eManager.Web2.Models
{
    public class EventClassCompListVM

    {

        public EventClassCompListVM()
    {

        this.ClassName = ClassName;
        this.CompName = CompName;
    }

        public int ECCLkey { get; set; }
        public int CompeditorId { get; set; }
        public int Comp_EventID { get; set; }
        public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
        public int EventID { get; set; }
        public int ClassID { get; set; }
        public string CompName { get; set; }
        public string EventName { get; set; }
        public string CompMetricName { get; set; }
        public double CompMetric { get; set; }
        public int MaxComp { get; set; }
        public string ClassName { get; set; }
        public int ClassOrder { get; set; }
        public int EventClassID { get; set; }
        public bool IsCrossOver { get; set; }
        public int Event_Class_CompeditorsId {get; set; }
   }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult BuildEventClassReports()
    {
        var model = (from o in _db.Events
                     join o2 in _db.Event_Classes on o.EventID equals o2.EventID
                     where o.EventID.Equals(o2.EventID)
                     join o3 in _db.Event_Class_Compeditors_s on o2.EventClassID equals o3.EventClassID
                     where o2.EventClassID.Equals(o3.EventClassID)
                     join o4 in _db.Compeditors on o3.CompeditorId equals o4.CompeditorId
                     where o3.CompeditorId.Equals(o4.CompeditorId)
                     join o5 in _db.Class_Definitions on o2.ClassID equals o5.Class_Definition_ID
                     where o2.ClassID.Equals(o5.Class_Definition_ID)
                     where o.CurrentEvent.Equals(true)
                     orderby o2.ClassOrder

                     //orderby o3.Comp_EventID

                     select new EventClassCompListVM
                     {
                         ClassID = o2.ClassID,
                         EventName = o.EventName,
                         EventDate = o.Date_End,
                         ClassName = o5.Class_Name,
                         Comp_EventID = o3.Comp_EventID,
                         ClassOrder = o2.ClassOrder,
                         CompName = (o4.FirstName + " " + o4.LastName),
                         IsCrossOver = o3.IsCrossOver

                     }).ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Html.DisplayFor(g => group.Key)

Worked great for the one item in the data that was heading the grouped elements